# How to make a material table row dont show text from greater than its width?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

First, I measured the size of the column with js, then I get to set a specific width for each character. 
Now, it works correctly, I mean when page loading, each row that its text size is greater than the row width, will show a part of the text + ' ...'.
But I want to show its full text in a popup, and it not works.

I need help so fast.
Do you know how can I fix this??

Comment: Post the [mcve] please

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for this? You can apply this class to your Mat-Table.

Try this CSS:

```css
.text {
  max-width: 100px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
.text:hover {
  overflow: visible;
}
```

```html
<div class="text">
  This is overflowed text
</div>
```

[`Stackblitz`](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-sxdtn6)

Answer (score 1):

You can use css for that.
Check below code.

```css
.overflow-ellipsis {
  white-space: nowrap; 
  max-width: 50px; 
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis; 
  border: 1px solid #000000;
}
```

```html
<h4>Normal text</h4>
<div>Hello world!</div>
<h4>With css</h4>
<div class="overflow-ellipsis">Hello world!</div>
```

Comment: Yeah I know but it not works on material table. I mean infact it makes material table nowrap and then it will not be responsive.

Comment: @Aurthur Try with using `max-width`, It might be helpful.

Comment: No it also not works.
I tried it before.

Comment: @Aurthur Please provide the stackblitz if possible

Comment: Problem solved !